# user control v/s custom control for image viewer

Tags: c#, user-controls, custom-controls

I would like to create an image viewer. I do not know where to start. Could you please give me some tips to start with.

I have the following point in my mind

- Create a custom control, override the paint event. Use properties to read, flip, rotate and zoom the images
- Create a user control with a panel inside, set the background to the image while i set the public property 'read'. Implement properties to rotate, flip,zoom

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @AndrewS: I use WinForms. Which one is best WinForms or WPF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use WPF instead winforms 
Zoom, Pan example using WPF : http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2009/06/02/pan-and-zoom-updated.aspx

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873%28VS.100%29.aspx) topic has sample codes for rotation etc:

> This topic provides an introduction to
>   the Microsoft Windows Presentation
>   Foundation Imaging Component. WPF
>   Imaging enables developers to display,
>   transform, and format images.
>
> This topic contains the following
>   sections.
>
> ```
> WPF Imaging Component
> WPF Image Formats
> Displaying Images in WPF
> Image Metadata
> Codec Extensibility
> Related Topics
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should first Learn GDI+, [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=ElAaTGP__U0C&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=learning%20gdi%2b&source=bl&ots=Ahz1R4fYtK&sig=LwawJhY35uyMWgtSYMV7Ua6jcAU&hl=en&ei=0HfPTaK7AarL0QH4--HfDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=learning%20gdi%2b&f=false) book (GDI+ Programming With C#) is very good for
 Learning GDI+ after reading , You'll can create an image viewer.

Comment: Do you believe that for creating simple Image viewer he should learning GDI+ ?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to show the image, PictureBox springs to mind a part from what you already suggests (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx).

When it comes to editing, you should avoid GetPixel() and SetPixel() which are beyond slow, and instead gain access to the the bits either through pointers using the `unsafe` keyword or by the Marshall Class.

Use the LockBits() method of your bitmap to get a BitmapData-object, and the fun shall begin!

Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20121203144033/http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm